# Distinct not applying on Following query

Tags: sql-server

```
Select Distinct top 100  Uid,ProDate,ProTime,min(Auto_No) As Auto_No
from Has_Swipedata 
where  format(Prodate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = Format(Getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy') and
       Is_Active='N' and
       Uid not like '%[^0-9]%' and Uid != '' 
Group by Uid, ProDate, ProTime
```

Table Data from Above Query :
    Uid      ProDate    ProTime             Auto_No

```
4057    2017-06-14  16:51:12.0000000    1584

4057    2017-06-14  16:51:13.0000000    1585

4057    2017-06-14  16:51:15.0000000    1586
```

Expected Result:

```
Uid      ProDate    ProTime             Auto_No

4057    2017-06-14  16:51:12.0000000    1584
```

Comment: Distinct Should be applied only on UID column. Where Protime, Auto_No Always difference

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Already Tried: Select Distinct top 100  Uid,ProDate,ProTime,min(Auto_No) As Auto_No from Has_Swipedata 
where (Uid = (Select Distinct(Uid) from HAS_Swipedata)) and format(Prodate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = Format(Getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy') and Is_Active='N' and Uid not like '%[^0-9]%' and Uid != '' 
Group by Uid, ProDate, ProTime

Comment: GIves Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Your call `FORMAT()` looks - uhm - weird... What is the data type or column `Prodate`. If its `DATETIME` you might have differing time parts? Better than this `format()`-thing was something like `CAST(Prodate AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` (as long as `Prodate` is a *real* date type. In this case you should cast your `Prodate` to `DATE` in all places (btw: this cast is *sargable*!)

Comment: Why `distinct` with `Group by` ? `Group by` will return distinct rows by definition.

Comment: distinct checks every column so the result is correct. What is your rule for only getting this one record ?

Comment: Only one distinct uid to be selected which has earliest time saved in protime. where Uid may be multiple with different Protime also Uid Has multiple different records

Comment: Basically as of now Distinct Uid needed irrespective of other columns and where condition shouldn't be changed

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to format the dates to strings to compare dates. If `ProDate` is a `date` datatype already, compare to `convert(date,getdate())`.

This gets the first/min `Auto_No` for each `Uid` and `ProDate`, along with the `ProTime` for that `Auto_No`.

using `cross apply()`:

```
select distinct top 100 
    sd.Uid
  , sd.ProDate
  , x.ProTime
  , x.Auto_No as Auto_No
from Has_Swipedata sd
  cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from Has_Swipedata i
    where i.Uid = sd.UID
      and i.ProDate = sd.ProDate
    order by i.Auto_No asc
    ) x
where sd.ProDate = convert(date,getdate())
  and sd.Is_Active = 'N'
  and sd.Uid not like '%[^0-9]%'
  and sd.Uid != ''
```

---

or using an inner join:

```
select top 100 
    sd.Uid
  , sd.ProDate
  , sd.ProTime
  , x.Auto_No as Auto_No
from Has_Swipedata sd
  inner join (
    select i.Uid, i.ProDate, Auto_No = min(i.Auto_No) 
    from Has_Swipedata i
    group by i.Uid, i.ProDate
  ) x
    on sd.Uid = x.Uid
   and sd.ProDate = x.ProDate
   and sd.Auto_No = x.Auto_No
where sd.ProDate = convert(date,getdate())
  and sd.Is_Active = 'N'
  and sd.Uid not like '%[^0-9]%'
  and sd.Uid != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at desired result, my guess is

```
Select top(1) with ties Uid, ProDate, ProTime, Auto_No 
from Has_Swipedata 
where  format(Prodate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = Format(Getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy') and
       Is_Active='N' and
       Uid not like '%[^0-9]%' and Uid != '' 
order by row_number() over(partition by Uid,ProDate order by Auto_No)
```

Demo

```
select top(1) with ties Uid, ProDate, ProTime, Auto_No 
from 
(values
 (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:12.0000000',   1584),
 (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:13.0000000',   1585),
 (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:15.0000000',   1586),
 (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:12.0000000',   1587),
 (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:13.0000000',   1588),
 (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:15.0000000',   1589)
) Has_Swipedata (Uid,ProDate,ProTime, Auto_No)
order by row_number() over(partition by Uid,ProDate order by Auto_No)
```

returns

```
    Uid ProDate ProTime Auto_No
1   4057    2017-06-14  16:51:12.0000000    1584
2   4058    2017-06-14  16:51:12.0000000    1587
```

If you need only first 100 Uid + ProDate then wrap the query with Select top(100) ...

```
select top(100) *
from (
    select top(1) with ties Uid, ProDate, ProTime, Auto_No 
    from 
    (values
     (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:12.0000000',   1584),
     (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:13.0000000',   1585),
     (4057,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:15.0000000',   1586),
     (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:12.0000000',   1587),
     (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:13.0000000',   1588),
     (4058,    '2017-06-14',  '16:51:15.0000000',   1589)
    ) Has_Swipedata (Uid,ProDate,ProTime, Auto_No)
    order by row_number() over(partition by Uid,ProDate order by Auto_No)
) result
```

Comment: This will return only single row, Where Uid Has multiple varchar value and its needed 100 data to be selected for futher process with 4 column selected

Comment: No, it will return a single row for every Uid + ProDate. See demo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe applying the same rule of Auto_No in ProTime generates the expected result:

```
Select top 100  
    Uid, ProDate, min(ProTime) as ProTime, min(Auto_No) As Auto_No
from Has_Swipedata 
where  Prodate = convert(date, GETDATE()) and
       Is_Active='N' and
       Uid not like '%[^0-9]%' and Uid != '' 
Group by Uid, ProDate
```

Or provide more data samples with expected results.